# Capture a String of More than 1 word and turn it into a single string separated by dashes

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm working with a wordpress site. I made a function with javascript that adds a class to the body tag that allows to show a different background according to the category. It works well when the category is a single word. But when I have a category that consists of 2 words or more it stops working. This is the code:

```
 ( window.onload=function() {
   let cat =   document.querySelector('.cats').lastElementChild.textContent;
   let body = document.querySelector('body');  

   if(cat.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
   cat.replace(' ','-');

   body.classList.add(cat.toLowerCase());
   } else {

   body.classList.add(cat.toLowerCase());
   }

   })();
```

If the category is "dentist" then this string is added to the body tag but if it is "General Doctor" it is no longer working.

I use functions.php to call this function only when it is a post using if_single ().

I try using replace() to replace the space for a dash but I am not implementing it correctly.

What can I do so that something like "General Physician" can be turned into a string like: "general-physician" which can be added as a class to the body tag?

Comment: try using this `[A-Z]+[a-z]+ +[A-Z]+[a-z]+(?!\s)` regex to see if the pattern matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use replace, the string's value won't be change.
Try this:

```
cat = cat.replace(/ /g,'-');
```

Comment: I tried your suggested modification and it is now working, now single name categories as well as 2 word ones get modified and added to the body tag as a class. Not sure why yet but I will look over your code. Thanks!

Comment: Ok found why: 

It's a regular expression where the \s means "match whitespace" and the g is a flag which means "global", i.e. match all whitespace, not just the first.

Answer (score 1):

First, `querySelector` hooks only the first selector met. If you want to verify each element with that class name, use instead `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByClassName`.

Second, related to your question, in this way, `replace` only replaces the first occurrence. You should replace that with:
`cat.replace(/\s/g, "");`

But, also you have to reassign it:
`cat = cat.replace(/\s/g, "");`